# Definition of exact sequence of functors.

Tags: category-theory

What is meant by an "exact sequence of functors" in an abelian category? My guess is the following: a sequence of the form:

$0 \rightarrow A \stackrel{f} \rightarrow B \stackrel{g} \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$

where $A,B,C$ are functors are the maps are natural transformations. Does the term "exact" means that for every object $D$ of the common domain of the categories we always have an exact sequence:

$0 \rightarrow A(D) \stackrel{f_{D}} \rightarrow B(D) \stackrel{g_{D}} \rightarrow C(D) \rightarrow 0$?

What are some examples of exact sequence of functors?

Comment: That is correct. In fact, the category of functors (with values in a given abelian category) is itself an abelian category, so this does not need a separate definition.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: ah, so only the codomain must be abelian, thanks, can you please provide an example of an exact sequence of functors?

Comment: @user10: for example, let $Z_n(X)$ denote singular $n$-cycles ($X$ is a topological space), $B_n(X)$ denote singular $n$-boundaries, and let $H_n(X)$ denote singular $n$-homology. Then $0 \to B_n(-) \to Z_n(-) \to H_n(-) \to 0$ is, more or less by construction, an exact sequence of functors from $\text{Top}$ to $\text{Ab}$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: thank you, if you can post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find the definition you want by taking the categorical point of view.  That is, consider the category of functors that you are interested in.  Objects are the (appropriate) functors, and morphisms are the corresponding natural transformations.  Such a category has zero objects and so we can ask whether kernels (cokernels) exist, and if so, are they the same as "objectwise" kernels (resp. cokernels).  This of course amounts to checking for a universal property.  Left/right exactness can be stated as the property of preserving kernels (resp. cokernels).  This should provide the answer.